# Cannot run node-redis-session lib

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, redis

I've installed the node-redis-session dependency and in the first time runs fine, but i've deleted the created cookies of the browser, and now I cannot make it run again.

This is the error message

```
TypeError: Object object has no method 'hasOwnProperty'
at ~/../server/node_modules/node-redis-session/lib/index.js:57:22
```

And this is an extract of the code (line 57)

```
var sid;
if (!req.cookies.hasOwnProperty(cookieName)) {
  //easy to find in redis with command "keys * s|*"
  sid = 's|'+generateSid();
  req.cookies[cookieName] = sid;
  res.cookie(cookieName, sid, { expires: new Date(new Date().getTime()+expireTime), httpOnly: true });
}
```

If you make a console.log(req.cookies) is an empty object.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bracket notation to check if the property exists.

```
if (!req.cookies[cookieName]) {
 ...
}
```